# Convert a string to its Rövarspråket equivalent

Tags: code-golf, string

### Rövarspråket

[Rövarspråket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B6varspr%C3%A5ket) is a word game played by Swedish children, from the books about Kalle Blomkvist by Astrid Lindgren.

The basic rules are as follows (from Wikipedia):

- Every consonant (spelling matters, not pronunciation) is doubled, and
  an o is inserted in-between.
- Vowels are left intact.

A few examples:

- "hello" -> "hohelollolo"
- "Min svävare är full med ål" -> "MoMinon sosvovävovarore äror fofulollol momedod ålol"

Swedish consonants are the same as the English ones, so the program should work with both Swedish and English entries.

The letter "y" is taken as a consonant in this case - as most of the time it is.

---

### Your Task:

Write a program to convert a string of Swedish letters, inputted through a function or through stdin, into its Rövarspråket equivalent.  Shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: @MartinBüttner Clarified my question further - it should work with Swedish (as it is a Swedish word-game).

Comment: What is the meaning of alphabetical entries ?

Comment: @Optimizer A string of only alphabetical characters.  Sorry, I worded it badly, I'll edit

Comment: do you mean English alphabets a-zA-Z ?

Comment: @Optimizer It should work with Swedish - however the consonants are the same in both Swedish and English.  Will clarify question.

Comment: ah, i see . . . .

Comment: In the case of a function, should the output be returned or printed to stdout/closest alternative?

Comment: How should we treat non letters? At least spaces show up in the second example.

Comment: On a side note: 'Y' is considered a vowel in Swedish

Answer (score 14):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 14 + 5 = 19 bytes

Retina is a language that is essentially just .NET regex with as little overhead as possible. The code for this program consists of two files:

```
i`[b-z-[eiou]]
```

```
$0o$0
```

This reads the input on STDIN and prints the output to STDOUT.

If you call the files `pattern.rgx` and `replacement.rpl`, you can run the program simply like

```
echo "hello" | ./Retina pattern.rgx replacement.rpl
```

### Explanation

This is pretty straightforward, but let me add some explanation anyway (mostly about how Retina works). If Retina is invoked with 2 files it is automatically assumed to operate in "Replace mode", where the first file is the regex and the second file is the pattern.

Retina can be configured (which includes `RegexOptions` and other options) by prepending the regex with `` ` `` and a configuration string. In this case I'm only giving it `i` which is the normal regex modifier for case insensitivity.

As for the regex itself, it uses .NET's character class subtraction to match any consonant in the ASCII range. The replacement then just writes the match back twice with an `o` in between.

Comment: Are you missing an `a` in your vowel character class?

Comment: @BrianGordon No, I'm starting the character class from `b`, so I don't need to subtract `a`.

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen nested, subtractive character ranges before. Is that just a .NET thing?

Comment: I feel like you need to count at least one character for the delimiting between the two files. that would be a semicolon or newline in another language. it's the space between the filenames if you want to get picky about where the character comes from in this language.

Comment: @Sparr yes, that's the policy now, but that policy is newer than this challenge/answer. [For reference](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4934/8478) (In fact, if you look at the time stamps, you can see that I pushed for the policy *because* of this answer, but applying rules like that throughout the site retroactively doesn't make much sense.)

Comment: @MartinBüttner sure, but it doesn't have to be policy to be right.

Answer (score 12):

**Using Unix KSH  <s>27</s> <s>28</s> <s>32</s> 27 bytes**  (or 21 if we only count inside sed command)

Thanks to the suggestions of others :) Appreciated.

.. I got down to this:

```
sed 's/[^AEIOUÅÄÖ ]/&o&/ig'
```

(allowed for spaces and Swedish characters)

```
echo "hello" | sed 's/[BCDFGHJ-NP-TV-Z]/&o&/ig'
hohelollolo
echo "HELLO" | sed 's/[BCDFGHJ-NP-TV-Z]/&o&/ig'
HoHELoLLoLO
echo "QuIcKlY Now" | sed 's/[BCDFGHJ-NP-TV-Z]/&o&/ig'
QoQuIcocKoKlolYoY NoNowow
```

Comment: [the `i` modifier to the `s` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command)

Comment: Also, I think it is allowable to claim your answer is a `sed` program, and just count the bytes between the single quotes

Comment: I was trying to add it .. but it wouldn't work ... any ideas ?  (tried: "-i" "-I", tried "/Ig", "/gI" .. etc .. nothing worked :(

Comment: `s/[^AEIOU]/&o&/ig` seems to work.. for single words at least... you'll need to exclude spaces as well

Comment: what Unix shell are you in? I'm using KSH: and getting command garbled

Comment: bash, though the shell shouldn't matter, so long as your sed program is in single quotes

Comment: Also watch out for the swedish vowels `ö`, `å`, etc - these need excluding too.  Might be better to use a whitelist of just the consonants `s/[BCDFGHJ-NP-TV-Z]/&o&/ig`

Comment: I've setup a chat room .. can we continue there ?  same name as this thread ;)

Comment: I don't think I have the GNU extension on my system :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22249/discussion-between-digitaltrauma-and-ditto).

Comment: I would make it 'sed' and use "s/[^AEIOUÅÄÖ ]/&o&/ig", which covers Swedish vowels and spaces for 25 bytes.

Comment: @swstephe ... cool, thanks .. was trying to do the not vowels, but wasn't sure of the swedish chars :)

Answer (score 8):

## CJam, <s>32</s> 30 bytes

```
q{_eu'[,66>"EIOU"-#)g{'o1$}*}/
```

This is a full program reading from STDIN and printing to STDOUT. It works for arbitrary Unicode input and treats the following 42 characters as consonants:

```
BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%7B_eu'%5B%2C66%3E%22EIOU%22-%23)g%7B'o1%24%7D*%7D%2F&input=Min%20sv%C3%A4vare%20%C3%A4r%20full%20med%20%C3%A5l.)

### Explanation

```
q                              "Slurp STDIN.";
 {                          }/ "For each character...";
  _eu                          "Duplicate and convert to upper case.";
     '[,66>                    "Get a string from B to Z using range and slice.";
           "EIOU"-             "Remove the remaining four vowels.";
                  #            "Find the position of the character in this string or
                                -1 if the character can't be found.";
                   )g          "Increment, take signum, which gives 1 for consonants, 
                                and 0 otherwise.";
                     {    }*   "Repeat this block that many times, i.e. do nothing for
                                non-consonants.";
                      'o       "Push an 'o'.";
                        1$     "Copy the current character.";
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, <s>59</s> <s>57</s> <s>55</s> <s>44</s> bytes

```js
s=>s.replace(/(?![eiou])[b-z]/gi,"$&o$&")
```

Thanks to Masterzagh for reminding me that a function would be acceptable as well, and for his regex tip regarding backreferences without capturing!

Longer version with input/output:

```js
alert(prompt().replace(/(?![eiou])[b-z]/gi,"$&o$&"));
```

Displays a prompt box to enter the string, then shows a dialog containing the Rövarspråket output. The code uses a regex to double the consonants and insert `o`s.

Comment: "Write a program to convert a string of Swedish letters, inputted through a function or through stdin", You can make it `s=>alert(s.replace(/(?![eiou])([b-z])/gi,"$1o$1"));`

Comment: And since it wasn't asked to output, you don't need the alert either.

Comment: One more thing, you can [backreference without capturing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12311199/7366285). Basically do `s=>s.replace(/(?![eiou])[b-z]/gi,"$&o$&")`, since `$&` means current match you can remove the parenthesis that capture your letter and while you're at it save another byte by removing the semicolon at the end.

Comment: @Masterzagh That's cool, thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, <s>46</s> 44 bytes

```r
t->replace(t,r"(?![eiou])[b-z]"i,s->s*"o"*s)
```

This creates an anonymous function that takes a single string input and prints the Rövarspråket equivalent. To call it, give it a name, e.g. `f=t->...`.

Not much has really been golfed here, other than spaces after the commas in `replace()`.

Here we're using 3 arguments in the `replace()` function: the input string, the regular expression for identifying substrings, and a replacement. Julia denotes regular expression patterns by `r"..."`. Adding `i` to the end makes it case insensitive. This particular regex matches consonants. If a function is used for the replacement, the output is that function applied to each matched substring. The function we're using here takes a string `s` and returns `sos`, since `*` performs string concatenation in Julia. Thus the end result is the input string with each consonant doubled with an "o" between.

Examples:

```r
julia> f("Min svävare är full med ål")
"MoMinon sosvovävovarore äror fofulollol momedod ålol"

julia> f("hello")
"hohelollolo"

julia> f("Rövarspråket")
"RoRövovarorsospoproråkoketot"
```

Note that this will be 9 bytes longer if we have to print the result rather than return it. Awaiting confirmation from the OP.

---

**Edit:** Saved 2 bytes thanks to Martin Büttner!

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, <s>84</s> <s>73</s> 72 bytes

```
StringReplace[#,a:RegularExpression@"(?i)[BCDFGHJ-NP-TV-Z]":>a<>"o"<>a]&
```

Explanation:

- `RegularExpression@"(?i)[BCDFGHJ-NP-TV-Z]"` is a regex matching all consonants case-insensitively.
- `a:*..*:>a<>"o"<>a` creates a delayed rule to bind those consonants to `a`, and replace it with and o surrounded by itself.
- Finally, `StringReplace[#,*..*]&` creates a pure function applying that rule to every matching letter in its argument.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Thanks! Still new to Mathematica golfing...

Comment: @MartinBüttner Was going to do that anyways but got distracted by some notifications :P

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 81 bytes

```
x n|elem n"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ"=[n,'o',n]|1<2=[n]
f=(>>=x)
```

Usage: `f "Hello there!"` -> `"HoHelollolo tothoherore!"`.

I cannot cleverly construct the list of consonants without expensive `import`s. Even turning the letter to check to lowercase needs more bytes than simply listing both upper and lowercase consonants.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, 45

Use as a lambda function. Uses regular expression.

```
a->a.replaceAll("(?i)[b-z&&[^eiou]]","$0o$0")
```

[Try here](http://ideone.com/nhwZax)

Comment: "Write a program to..." This looks more like a function to me.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 61

I couldn't get a character class union or subtraction to work, and so I don't think Python has that feature. I had to use a negative lookahead instead.

```python
import re;f=lambda s:re.sub('(?i)(?![eiou])([b-z])',r'\1o\1',s)
```

Run it here: http://repl.it/fQ5

Link to the inverse: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/48182/34718

Answer (score 2):

## C 106

**Thanks to @ceilingcat for some very nice pieces of golfing - now even shorter**

```
x;main(c){for(;read(0,&c,1);printf("%s%s%s"+x*2,&c,x+"o",&c))x=c<66|c>122|c>90&c<98||index("EIOUeiou",c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYlBC8IgGED/iggNbQabh9FwdevQITr1A@RTQ3A6XBtC9ttt48HjwYPTG6CUJEZpPQH6NSESEbVUpGEVsJaKKVr/MQQf5h1cpyPfT6pxwFtQmi4wdF2Ga8v55r6pYOjPOVuvdCL4dn@@tA0LZkDFr5SH9Whe5SqjRjIisziHRq2QdH8)

Comment: How does the local variable `c` get declared?

Comment: @wjl global variables in C are zero initialized. Local variables are on the stack and are not initialized. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553559/how-are-local-and-global-variables-initialized-by-default   Variables with out a type default to int and since printf works on chars the code might have endian issues - I will check tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, I understand default initialization. I was just trying to nicely point out that this code does not compile since `c` isn't *declared* at all, e.g. `out.c:2:18: error: ‘c’ undeclared (first use in this function)`.

Comment: @wjl I guess it depends on the compiler.  It compiles and runs at ideone.com http://ideone.com/s7M5mZ when you choose C - any idea what the difference is?

Comment: Looks like a bug with ideone's compiler. If you fix the newline between `c[2];main` (necessary because `#define` doesn't end at a semicolon) it gives similar errors to GCC. Anyway, no big deal, it's still a fun code-golf, but you might actually need a few more characters to make this valid C. =)

Comment: @wjl I can't get ideone.com to fail to compile it by adding newlines.  With gcc on my own box it compiles fine (with warnings)  My version of gcc is: gcc (i686-posix-sjlj-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.9.2
Maybe it is a bug in gcc too?

Comment: @wjl Ok, I agree it is not valid C.  I can't get it to compile on my RS6000 because it doesn't like the ternary operator having two different types.  Of course it is xlc version 6 - a compiler from 2003.  I guess to make it valid C that would pass any compiler I would need to change it massively.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 33 Bytes

This answer is mostly regex-only, with a small amount of extra code to perform I/O.

```
$_=<>;s/[^aeiou\W]/$&o$&/gi;print
```

It's been a while since I've used Perl regexes, so this can probably be improved.

```
$_=<>;                              This takes input from STDIN `<>` and stores
                                    it into the default variable $_
      s/          /     /gi;        This is a case-(i)nsentive, (g)lobal, 
                                    (s)ubstitution regex.  Since no other
                                    variable is specified, it is applied to
                                    the default variable $_.
        [^aeiou\W]                  This matches any single character that 
                                    is a consonant, by using a double-
                                    negative ^\W to match only alphanumeric 
                                    characters excluding vowels.  Accented 
                                    vowels are not considered alphanumeric 
                                    by Perl.
                   $&o$&            This forms the replacement.  $& contains the 
                                    match (the consonant), so this replaces each 
                                    consonant with two copies of itself with 
                                    an 'o' in between.
                            print   This prints the result.  With no arguments, 
                                    it prints $_ by default.
```

Comment: Won't `[^aeiou]` still match å and other non-ASCII vowels?

Comment: @AlexA. I already noticed the problem.  It was a zero-character fix (`\s` to `\W`).

Comment: +1, most thorough explanation for Perl code I have seen on this site.

Answer (score 2):

### **Windows Batch, 235 bytes**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set d=qwrtypsdfghjklzxcvbnm
set #=%1
:x
if defined # (
for /l %%i in (0,1,20)do (
set m=!d:~%%i,1!
if /i !m!==%#:~0,1% set g=!g!!m!o)
set g=!g!%#:~0,1%
set #=%#:~1%
goto x)
echo %g%
```

Usage:

```
script.bat hello
```

Output:

```
hohelollolo
```

You might be wondering why I didnt set d to "aoui", checking for not-equals requires breaking out of a loop. Not everything that should work, does work, in batch. The script handles 1 word of characters [as they appear on your keyboard]. All spaces and newlines that are still present are required for the script to run.

*Windows XP or higher, required. Not tested in Windows 8 and above.*

Answer (score 2):

### **PowerShell - 35 bytes**

Just to show that PowerShell can compete in these sometimes too, and with the regex shamelessly stolen from Martin Büttner's Retina answer:

```
%{$_-replace'[b-z-[eiou]]','$0o$0'}
```

accepts string input from stdin

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <strike>16</strike> <strike>15</strike> 13 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)

```
žNDu«SD'o«€Ć‡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATwAw/9vc2FiaWX//8W@TkR1wqtTRCdvwqvigqzEhuKAof//TWluIHN2w6R2YXJlIMOkciBmdWxsIG1lZCDDpWw)

Comment: `.š` can be `u` (to uppercase) to save a byte. And nice answer!

Comment: I just had the feeling 13 bytes was possible.. Took me a bit to find it, though: [`žNDu«SD'o«€Ć‡`](https://tio.run/##ATwAw/9vc2FiaWX//8W@TkR1wqtTRCdvwqvigqzEhuKAof//TWluIHN2w6R2YXJlIMOkciBmdWxsIG1lZCDDpWw)

Comment: haha, I was searching for "capital" instead of upper, thanks for the improvements @KevinCruijssen

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 28 bytes

This is works in the obvious way by generating the consonants list on the fly using set-wise difference.

```
FNzpk+N?+\oN}rNZ-{G{"aeiou"k
```

Explanation coming soon.

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=FNzpk%2BN%3F%2B%5CoN%7DrNZ-%7BG%7B%22aeiou%22k&input=hello).

Comment: You can save 4 bits by removing 4 chars and replacing one char with another one.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clip 10](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Clip), 30

```
gx"((?i)[b-z&&[^eiou]])""$1o$1
```

Basic regex substitution.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <strike>25</strike> <strike>24</strike> 23

```
sm+d*+\od}rd0-G"aeoui"z
```

[Run it here.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sm%2Bd*%2B%5Cod%7Drd0-G%22aeoui%22z&input=Min+sv%C3%A4vare+%C3%A4r+full+med+%C3%A5l&debug=0)

Comment: One char of your solution is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

## K, 38 chars

```
f:{,/(1+2*~(_x)in"aeiouåäö ")#'x,'"o"}
  
-1 f"Min svävare är full med ål";
MoMinon sosvovävovarore äror fofulollol momedod ålol
```

Answer (score 1):

## K, 31 bytes

```
,/{(x,"o",x;x)9>" aeiouåäö"?x}'
```

A straightforward solution seems fairly competitive given that K lacks regexes. Select between the "XoX" form and "X" form based on whether each character was found in a lookup table of ignored vowels and join the resulting lists.

You can try it in your browser using [oK](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/index.html):

```
http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/index.html?run=%20%2C%2F%7B(x%2C%22o%22%2Cx%3Bx)9%3E%22%20aeiouåäö%22%3Fx%7D'%22Min%20svävare%20är%20full%20med%20ål%22
```

(Unfortunately I can't provide a clickable link because stack overflow doesn't appear to allow accented characters in URLs)

Answer (score 0):

## Golfscript, 35 bytes

```
{."aeiouåäö\n "?-1={."o"\}{}if}%
```

Expects the input to be on the stack. With input (50 bytes):

```
"#{STDIN.gets}"{."aeiouåäö\n "?-1={."o"\}{}if}%
```

Works with the swedish vovels å, ä and ö.

Comment: input is always on stack on GS

Answer (score 0):

## Sed (on command line), 28 bytes

```
sed 's/\([^aeiou]\)/\1o\1/g'
```

Either pipe the text in or type it direct. Just the sed code on its own is 22 bytes.

Comment: This also duplicates spaces and chars like `ä`.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 43

Thanks to @Masterzagh for saving on function syntax.

```
x=>x.replace(/[bcdfghj-np-tv-z]/gi,"$&o$&")
```

### <strike>JavaScript 62</strike>

```
function E(x){return x.replace(/[bcdfghj-np-tv-z]/gi,"$&o$&")}
```

Comment: Your function can be in the form of an anonymous arrow function like `x=>x.replace(/[bcdfghj-np-tv-z]/gi,"$&o$&")`.
Arrow functions work like this `name=(arg1, arg2)=>{code}`. `()` are not needed if there's only one argument and `{}` are not needed if there's only one line of code. Return is also not needed if the one line returns something.

Comment: And I forgot to say. You don't need to give it a name to solve the problem which only asked you to create a function.

Answer (score 0):

## R, 45 chars

```
gsub("([^aeiouäöå ])","\\1o\\1",readline(),i=T)
```

Simple regex. Reads from stdin. `i=T` stands for `ignore.case=TRUE` (thanks to partial matching of argument names), which makes `gsub` case insensitive.

Usage:

```
> gsub("([^aeiouäöå ])","\\1o\\1",readline(),i=T)
Min svävare är full med ål
[1] "MoMinon sosvovävovarore äror fofulollol momedod ålol"
> gsub("([^aeiouäöå ])","\\1o\\1",readline(),i=T)
hello
[1] "hohelollolo"
> gsub("([^aeiouäöå ])","\\1o\\1",readline(),i=T)
hElLo
[1] "hohElolLoLo"
```

Answer (score 0):

## <>< (Fish), 64 bytes

```
>" oieauåäöOIEAUÅÄÖ"0i:1+?!;01.
 :&=?\     l?!v&
^[0o&<&o"o"o:&<
```

It's not the shortest answer but I enjoy the challenge of programming in <><

[Try it out here](http://fishlanguage.com/playground/xx5w7wxAa3t3u6oJm)

Answer (score 0):

## golflua, 36 bytes

```lua
B=I.r():g("[^aeiou%W ]","%1o%1")w(B)
```

Simple pattern-matching: take stdin, then find the non-vowels (`%W` takes care of non-alphanumeric chars) & insert an `o` between the two replacements. Sadly, doing all this within the write (i.e., `w(I.r():g(....))`) also output the count of insertions, though it saved 3 chars. A Lua equivalent would be

```lua
line = io.read()
rovar = line:gsub("[^aeiou%W ]","%1o%1")
print(rovar)
```

Answer (score 0):

## REXX, 107 bytes

```
parse arg s
v='aeiouåäö '
o=
do until s=''
  parse var s l 2 s
  if verify(l,v)>0 then l=l'o'l
  o=o||l
  end
say o
```

"MoMinon sosvovävovarore äror fofulollol momedod ålol"

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
r\c_+io
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=clxjXytpbw&input=IkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCEi)

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 75 bytes

```
x n|elem n[x|x<-['B'..'z'],notElem x"EIOUaeiou"]=[n,'o',n]|1<2=[n]
f=(>>=x)
```

This is a slight improvement on [nimi's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/48126/92098) (unfortunately I can't comment yet) which uses a "clever" way to generate a list of consonants (`[x|x<-['B'..'z'],notElem x"EIOUaeiou"]`) that saves 6 bytes over just listing them out.

In this case `['B'..'z']` expands to `` "BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" ``.

While some non-letter characters are included in the list of consonants, these don't include any punctuation or spaces so it should work for any regular sentence.

Usage: `f "Hello there!"` -> `"HoHelollolo tothoherore!"`.