# Decode a Rövarspråket string

Tags: code-golf, string

This question is the inverse of [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48117/convert-a-string-to-its-r%C3%B6varspr%C3%A5ket-equivalent) by [James Williams](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/25274/james-williams).

---

### Rövarspråket

[Rövarspråket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B6varspr%C3%A5ket) is a word game played by Swedish children, from the books about Kalle Blomkvist by Astrid Lindgren.

The basic rules used during encoding are as follows (from Wikipedia):

- Every consonant (spelling matters, not pronunciation) was doubled, and
  an o was inserted in-between.
- Vowels were left intact.

A few examples of decoding:

- "hohelollolo" -> "hello"
- "MoMinon sosvovävovarore äror fofulollol momedod ålol" -> "Min svävare är full med ål"

Swedish consonants are the same as the English ones, so the program should work with both Swedish and English entries.

The letter "y" is taken as a consonant in this case - as most of the time it is.

---

### Your Task:

Write a program to convert a Rövarspråket string of Swedish letters, inputted through a function or through stdin, into its decoded equivalent.  Shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: Are uppercase letters treated the same way as their lowercase counterparts? e.g. does `HOHELOLLOLO` become `HELLO`?

Comment: In the case of a function, should results be returned, printed to stdout/closest alternative, or either?

Comment: @AlexA. I think any of those are fine.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Oops, no, caught me. It should indeed be `HoHELoLLoLO`.

Comment: @Sp3000 Sorry, I was mistaken, the `o`s in the middle must be lowercase. So `HOHELOLLOLO` is not a valid input. If the input is invalid your program is allowed to do whatever, it will only be tested for valid inputs.

Comment: Wouldn't `HOHELOLLOLO` then return itself because there are no lowercase `o`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 19 + 2 = 21 bytes

Retina strikes again! The code for this program consists of two files:

```
i`([b-z-[eiou]])o.
```

```
$1
```

This reads the input on STDIN and prints the output to STDOUT.

If you call the files `pattern.rgx` and `replacement.rpl`, you can run the program simply like

```
echo "hohelollolo" | ./Retina pattern.rgx replacement.rpl
```

### Explanation

[As for the previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/48120/8478), if Retina is invoked with 2 files it is automatically assumed to operate in "Replace mode", where the first file is the regex and the second file is the pattern.

Retina can be configured (which includes `RegexOptions` and other options) by prepending the regex with `` ` `` and a configuration string. In this case I'm only giving it `i` which is the normal regex modifier for case insensitivity.

The pattern itself is a bit more interesting this time. It still uses .NET's character class subtraction to match any consonant in the ASCII range, but then it also matches the following `o` as well as the character after it (i.e. the copy of the consonant). The replacement then just writes the captured consonant back.

You might be wondering why this is not ambiguous in a case like `lololol -> lol`. The trick is that matches cannot overlap and are always found from left-to-right. So whenever I encounter a consonant, I include the next two character in the match and replace all of them - the search continues after this. It's quite easy to convince yourself that this kind of greedy algorithm will always decode the input correctly. In fact the pattern could even have been

```
i`([b-z-[eiou]])..
```

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, <s>61</s> 43 bytes

```ruby
t->replace(t,r"(?![eiou])[b-z]o."i,s->s[1])
```

This creates an anonymous function which accepts a string as input and returns the inverse Rövarspråket transformation of the string. It's the exact inverse of [my Julia answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/48135/20469) to the Rövarspråket challenge. To call it, give it a name, e.g. `f=t->...`.

The `replace()` function is doing all of the work here. The first argument is the input string, the second is a regular expression pattern (which in Julia is given as a string preceded by `r`), and the third is the replacement.

For the regex, we're matching all pairs of consonants separated by an "o". For the replacement, we're taking the match and extracting only the first character, which is the consonant.

Examples:

```ruby
julia> f("hohelollolo")
"hello"

julia> f("MoMinon sosvovävovarore äror fofulollol momedod ålol")
"Min svävare är full med ål"
```

Questions? Just let me know. Suggestions? Very welcome as always!

---

**Edit:** Saved 18 bytes thanks to Martin Büttner!

Comment: @MartinBüttner: Has anyone told you recently that you're awesome?

Comment: I've read something on meta. ;) (And +1 for using Julia!)

Comment: Btw, you can save two more bytes by mimicking character class subtraction with a lookahead: `(?![eiou])[b-z]o.` (I think this also goes for a lot of answers on the original challenge.)

Comment: @MartinBüttner: I think meta did a good job of getting the point across. :) And thanks for the support! I've been using Julia for a couple years and I try to use it around PPCG whenever I can. It's a good way to learn new things. Also, thanks once again!!

Answer (score 1):

### Sed, <strike>13</strike>, <strike>15</strike>, <strike>16</strike>, 28

```
s/\([^äöåaeiou]\)o\1/\1/g
```

Run it like this:

```
echo MoMinon sosvovävovarore äror fofulollol momedod ålol | sed 's/\([^äöåaeiou]\)o\1/\1/g'
```

Output:

```
Min svävare är full med ål
```

Comment: I would consider `-r` part of the bytecount, just like a Python solution has to count `re.sub`.

Comment: Your solution fails for `ooo`, which incorrectly gets decoded to `o`. It should stay `ooo`.

Comment: @Thor: No Swedish words have to contain "ooo" for "o" to be invalid output because the Rövarspråket-transformed words aren't constrained to be actual Swedish words.

Comment: orlp and AlexA: You are correct, I will use a non-vowel group instead.

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 47

Use as a lambda function. Works the exact same way as [Martin's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/48142/32700).

```
a->a.replaceAll("(?i)([b-z&&[^eiou]])o.","$1");
```

[Try here](http://ideone.com/ROAFLy)

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 27

```
VzJ:zZhZpkJ~Zhy}rJ0-G"aeoui
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 46

This turns out to be some language-specific sintax around a regexp.
ES6 is quite short. Too bad we miss [subtraction](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html)

```
F=s=>s.replace(/([b-df-hj-np-tv-z])../gi,'$1')
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 36 bytes

Roughly uses the strategy in [my previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/48136/33208).

```
StringReplace[#,a_~~"o"|"O"~~a_:>a]&
```

Explanation:

- `"o"|"O"` matches the lettter O insensitively.
- `a_~~*..*~~a_:>a` matches any character `a` followed by an O followed by `a` again, and replaces it with `a`.
- Finally, `StringReplace[#,*..*]&` creates a pure function applying that rule to every matching sequence in its argument.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP - <strike>65</strike> 66

```
$s=$argv[1];echo preg_replace("/([^aeiou])o([^aeiou])/i","$1",$s);
```

Comment: I don't think this is going to work correctly with `ä`, `ö` and `å` or upper case vowels.

Comment: It works for upper case, But yes not for other characters you mentions. It strictly for english only alphabets.

Comment: @MartinBüttner, You comment is correct. I copied another version do not have case insensitive (/i) modifier. However my code is still run on local with out this modifier for some unknown reasons. Still i added a "i". One more byte.

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 61

The inverse is conveniently is the same length as the [original](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/48137/34718).

```python
import re;g=lambda s:re.sub('(?i)(?![eiou])([b-z])o.',r'\1',s)
```

Or alternatively:

```python
import re;g=lambda s:re.sub('(?i)(?![eiou])([b-z])o.','\\1',s)
```

Run it here: http://repl.it/f3N

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 65

```js
function R(x){return x.replace(/([bcdfghj-np-tv-z])o\1/gi, "$1")}
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript ES6, 108 bytes

```js
F=s=>{
  for(n='',i=0;i<s.length;n+=c)c=s[i],i+=~'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'.indexOf(c.toLowerCase())?3:1
  return n
}
```

To make this interesting, I tried to do this entirely without regular expressions, which is why it is so long. It works by iterating over the string, copying each letter over to a new string. If it encounters a consonant, it skips the next two letters, which would be o + that letter. Use the snippet for a GUI alert and ES5.

```js
F=function(s){for(n='',i=0;i<s.length;n+=c)c=s[i],i+=~'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'.indexOf(c.toLowerCase())?3:1
return n}

alert(F('hohelollolo')+'\n'+F('MoMinon sosvovävovarore äror fofulollol momedod ålol'))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 15 bytes

```apl
([^aeiou])o.
\1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn6/18jOi4xNTO/NFYzX48rxvD//4z8jNSc/BwgyufyzffNzMvPUyjOLy7LLzu8BEgkFuUXpSocXgKkFNLy00ohShVy83NTU/JTFA4vBfK4PPI9XH3yfYDI/78hAA)

PCRE Replace…

`([^aeiou])o.` non-vowel (and call this the first capturing group), "o", any character

with…

`\1` the first capturing group