# The Farfallino Alphabet

Tags: code-golf

**The Task**

Your task is to create a program or a function that, given a sentence, outputs it translated to the [Farfallino language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farfallino_alphabet). 'Y' is treated as a consonant.

The usual rules for farfallino alphabet are based on the substitution of each vowel with a 3 letter sequence where the vowel itself is repeated with an interceding f.

```
house → hofoufusefe
lake → lafakefe
star → stafar
king → kifing
search → sefeafarch
```

**More examples:**

Hello World

> Hefellofo Woforld

Code golfs are nice, yuppy!

> Cofodefe gofolfs afarefe nificefe, yufuppy!

When you come across a double vowel syllable (the vowels must match, like *door, boots, reed, etc.*) you must omit the 2nd vowel.
**This rule is mandatory**

Cool game

> WRONG: Cofoofol gafamefe
>
> RIGHT: Cofofol gafamefe

**More examples, again:**

```
Aardvark → Afafardvafark
Artisan → Afartifisafan
ASCII → AfaSCIfifi
NASA → NAfaSAfa
Oobleck → Ofofobleck
I'M DEAD! → Ifi'M DEfeAfaD!
Abc → Afabc
```

**Input**

Your input must be an ASCII string.

>2 consecutive vowels are not special. You have to handle 2 consecutive vowels:

```
AAAH → AfafaAfaH
AAAAH → AfafaAfafaH
```

**How to win**

The shortest source code in bytes for each language wins.

1, 2, 3... go!

Comment: Reminds me of [l'argot louchébem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louch%C3%A9bem)

Comment: [Very similar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/48117/34531).

Comment: Do we need to handle upper and lowercase letters?  And if so, what should we get for `OoOoO`?

Comment: Too bad the sandbox wasn't used first. This one could have been whipped into shape in advance. I don't think the challenge is interesting enough without the double vowel requirement. It's a basic regular expression/substitution without much room for ingenuity.

Comment: At least one answer converts the vowels to lowecase (e.g. `Anabel` -> `afanafabefel`). Is this allowed?

Comment: I've updated the explanation for more clarity about the input string. @EriktheOutgolfer No. The input string should _not_ be altered.

Comment: So I can't take `Anabel` to `AfAnafabefel`?

Comment: Changing a challenge's spec to invalidate existing solutions is an automatic -1 from me. I'd -1 a second time, if I could, for not bothering to inform those that had posted those solutions.

Comment: This reminds me of [Ubbi Dubbi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubbi_dubbi)

Comment: Couple of things: 1) `Oobleck → Ofofoblefeck` not `Ofofobleck` 2) `AfaSCIfifi`, `AfafaAfaH`, and `AfafaAfafaH` are internally inconsistent. They should be either `AfaSCIfifi`, `AfafafaH`, and `AfafafafaH` *or* `AfaSCIfiIfi`, `AfaAfaAfaH`, and
`AfaAfaAfaAfaH`

Comment: I went through and tested every answer. Right now, none of them pass the `AAAH → AfafaAfaH` test case you added at the end. Since your edits have invalidated every single answer and the spec is still not entirely clear (why is it `AfafaAfaH` and not `AfAfaAfaH`?), I am going to close this question.

Comment: This challenge is being [discussed on meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16456/31716)

Answer (score 10):

## Japt, v2.0a0, 7 bytes

```
r\v_²íf
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=clx2X7LtZg==&input=ImhvdXNlIg==)

---

### Explanation

```
r           :Replace
 \v         :/[AEIOU]/gi
   _        :Pass each match through a function
    ²       :  Duplicate
     íf     :  Interleave "f"
```

> **Note**: This solution was posted *before* the "bonus" of handling double vowels was made a requirement and before the (apparent) requirement that when repeating an uppercase vowel the second occurrence should be lowercased. I don't much feel like wasting time on a challenge whose spec is constantly changing and invalidating the solutions that have already been posted, nor do I feel I should be expected to sacrifice 90 rep by deleting a solution that was valid at the time of posting.

Comment: Whoops, you answered before it was made mandatory. My bad.

Comment: Unfortunately, the double-vowel rule became mandatory, invalidating this answer.

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), 67 bytes

```js
f=
s=>s.replace(/([aeiou])\1*/gi,s=>[s[0],...s.toLowerCase()].join`f`)
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Includes the double vowel handling. Edit: Includes upper case too. Try `Aardvark`.

Comment: @3D1T0R Well, I was waiting for clarification from the OP, but I guess this will do for now.

Comment: It would be nice to have it edited into the post, but OP did say in a comment `@ngn I'd say the first one si the correct one. The input entered shouldn't impact the program imho so keep it simple` referring to ngn's comment `@Cris how does "Abc" translate to Farfallino? "Afabc", "AfAbc", or "AFAbc"?`. I'd take this as meaning that the way you now treat them is correct.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 27 bytes

```
'fžMDu+DŠδ.ø˜‡γεDÙlžMsåiÙ}?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATsAxP8wNWFiMWX//ydmxb5NRHUrRMWgzrQuw7jLnOKAoc6zzrVEw5lsxb5Nc8OlacOZfT///0Nvb2wgR2FtZQ)

Just a temporary fix for handling double vowels. I'll try to shorten this after my finals. Boo to rule changes!

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
'fžMDu+DŠδ.ø˜‡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/8wNWFiMWX//ydmxb5NRHUrRMWgzrQuw7jLnOKAof//aG91c2U)

If we only need to handle lowercase input, then this is [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v8wNWFiMWX//ydmxb5NRMWgzrQuw7jLnOKAof//aG91c2U).

#### How it works

- `'f` pushes the character literal **f** to the stack
- `žMDu+D` yields `aeiouAEIOU`; in the 11-byte version, it pushes `aeiou` to the stack; the leading `D` duplicates it (that is, it pushes two copies of it to the stack).
- `Šδ.ø˜` surrounds `f` with each vowel in the second copy
- `‡` performs the transliteration of the input from the first copy of the vowels to the second copy, the one in which all vowels surround a single **f**

Comment: This is incorrect for "Cool Game".  It produces "Cofoofol gafamefe" instead of "Cofofol gafamefe".

Comment: I see that is due to spec changes. I hadn't noticed the changes before, I will fix this later when I get back home.

Comment: I wouldn't have mentioned it if I'd noticed the change at the time.  So it goes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 bytes

```
;”f;ƊeØc$¡€F;⁷ḟ⁹fØc¤¥Ɲ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATgAx/9qZWxsef//O@KAnWY7xoplw5hjJMKh4oKsRjvigbfhuJ/igblmw5hjwqTCpcad////Y29vbGxhdA)

Handles the extra (now required) feature.

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
;”f;ƊeØc$¡€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/6UcPcNOtjXamHZySrHFr4qGnN/6N7DrcD6SwgftQwR0FBQVdX1w5IAVVG/v8fzaXuAdSarxCeX5SToq7DpZ6RX1qcCmLkJGaD6eKSxCIQnZ2Zlw7mpyYWJWeoc8UCAA)

Doesn't handle the double vowel feature.

```
;”f;ƊeØc$¡€
          €  For each character in the input, do the following.
         ¡   If:
     e       the character is in...
      Øc     the list 'aeiouAEIOU'
        $    (connects e and Øc into a single monad)
             then:
;            append
 ”f          the letter f
   ;         and append the initial character.
    Ɗ        Group ;”f; into a single monad.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>34</s> 30 bytes

```
i`[aeiou]
$0f$l
([aeiou])\1
$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lck9CsJAEAbQ/jvFCFsoWJgjiI03sFDBIZlshow7YX@KnD6msHy8LFUTd9umnyeLensjXMZgOP55enUI@0/eisB4FpTKGbOmiCKc@wl3MXN6eLYBNx@EottYiLNQ0l7OtLZlWQ/7uVHkr@CqrfoP)

First time using Retina...

*-2 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen*
*-2 bytes thanks to PunPun1000*

Comment: You can remove the two trailing new-lines to make it 32 bytes. Everything else would be the same as how I would post it if you hadn't already, so +1 from me.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks!

Comment: You can remove the parentheses in the first line and change the $1 to $0 in the second line (entire match instead of first group) for -2 bytes

Comment: You'll probably want to add a `$l` to fix the `Abc` case.

Comment: @PunPun1000 Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>80</s> 77 bytes

```python
lambda s:''.join(map(lambda c,C:c+('f'+c*(c!=C))*(c in'aeiouAEIOU'),s,s[1:]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY@xTsQwEER7vmJPFI65CAnKSFegCAkqKkQBFMbxJiaO17KTIl8fNg66pPLsvpmxHeaxI/@44OVrcWr4aRSkSoj7X7K@GFQo/pe6rCt9LgSKs74r9OlSS8knWC@UsTQ9Pb@@vQtZpjJ9PlTfUi4hWj8CFqKjKRkh4RY6QpqQJzQ3V@xUv1GnkOURpVHFjFigijvorW8z6C2yPCSMirrbMly1pnS34xfjHMEHRddkz2HeTTU1BlpymEBFA95qU8I8hTCfcqjmXzRczh7cXHzLOnt@jGaxujH7j6XkoFWDuVZgXiCv0Cx/)

---

Saved:

- -3 bytes, thanks to ovs.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 68 bytes

```java
s->s.replaceAll("([aeiou])","$1f$1").replaceAll("([aeiou])\\1","$1")
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZCxasMwEIb3PMVVZJAgMXgOLZgs9dAsHTokGS6y7Cg@S0aSA6b42V019diiggQ63Xe/PnTDO25vVTtLQu/hDbX5XAFoE5SrUSo4fJcA78Fp04Dky8GLXbyf4o7LBwxawgEMPMPsty8@c6qnOF4QccaPqLQdzoJt2Dqv1zkTv/dPp/yBMDHvfpL74UIxeXngbnUFXVRcLI5nQLH4jT6oLrNDyPrYCmS4ySRnVzt4xcTD9m@KsE1DUcIloTZqpZMUOnlNYq@KyMKHdVQl2b2tFDSWag/oFBgt1QbGoe/Hp3/MWoIGu/QXFBeZZoqyLBdqWk3zFw)

Or **77 bytes** if we have to handle uppercase vowels as well:

```java
s->s.replaceAll("(?i)([aeiou])","$1f$1").replaceAll("([AEIOUaeiou])\\1","$1")
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZBBa8MgFMfv/RRv0oNCG8i5bCOMwXpYdxhjh7SHV2NSG6NBTSGMfPbMdV52GBZ8oM/f8//DM15wfa7amSt0Dl5R6q8FgNRe2Bq5gN3PEeDdW6kb4DRuHNuE/hQqLOfRSw470HAPs1s/uMyKXoXxQilK6KNktEQhzXBgZEWWeb3MCfvLlMXz9u0jQvt9fuUImze/Ef1wVCEiJl2MrKALrlGnPACyKDo6L7rMDD7rw5VXmuqMU3IygxOEXbX/pxS2aShI2CTUBq30SwItPyWxF6GUgU9jVZVkn0wloDGqdoBWgJZcrGAc@n68u2HWKGiwS39BceRpBrdSyohNi2n@Bg)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->                             // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
  s.replaceAll("([aeiou])",     //  Replace every vowel with:
               "$1f$1")         //  the vowel, 'f', the vowel appended to each other
   .replaceAll("([aeiou])\\1",  //  Then replace every duplicated vowels
               "$1")            //  to a single one
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), <s>177</s> <s>163</s> 155 bytes

```
A+B:-append(A,B).
S-[H|T]-R:-S-T-Q,([I,[H,H],K]+Q,K-[H]-L,[I,[H,102,H,102,H],L]+R;[I,[H],K]+Q,K-[H]-L,[I,[H,102,H],L]+R;R=Q).
R-_-R.
S-R:-S-`aeiouAEIOU`-R.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY1Nq8IwEEX371fM21U6I@pSEakiVBSkqeKihDbYWAOxCakiwvvvffFjK@hmFmfuvcc6o01FzVW1bRROhySslXUZRDjtdH9SyuK/DSc2pJQ2lGCQLTCLMea45GGCS//ntMIn7fcG@LocVzxkowd/n32l2DjxLkY5sbvyISuEVOYSzRfrbeFxOyEoYqm1gZ1xuvQMoTk7VVf5/ihcE6QIrINwdeosdR2kfvHemZlSQmX0oQHhJNRqLxFuF2tvv19sGA2VOMlPGu0/)

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 81 bytes

```
func[s][foreach c{aoeiu}[replace/all replace/all s c rejoin[c"f"c]rejoin[c c]c]s]
```

Lowercase vowels only - it's much shorter now without using `parse`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc2xDgIhEATQ3q9YqU3s7YyNtY0FoViX5Q5dWQJSXIzfjjYa7OZNJpnCvp/YW7cKux5aIludDVoYaQZ6onJsL1s4CxJvUQTGXIE@vmpMlkww5L4AcuSq67nE9IAAZtZW2ax@FryNrIyF5qE4sojCWYv4oT2oZ5hUQgUsDCkSb2BpOS/rv5UKTHgfD/YJLyymvwE)

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 132 bytes

```
func[s][v: charset["aoeiuAOEIU"]parse s[any[copy n v n(prin rejoin[n"f"n"f"n])|
copy n v(prin rejoin[n"f"n])| copy n skip(prin n)]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zco9C8IwEMbxvZ/ivElBcO8mIugkCOIQIoT0YqPxLiRWKPjda@vLYodn@T3/RFW3p0rpwpWda9iqrNWjBFublOmu0Aj5Zrlbbw@o42CQleFWWYktMDyApzF5hkQX8awYHb6nZ8/i14yL/oXvm68@fgKeaa07B1hLkwmLAe@ApwUWPQZzHVkmk2z9rxsKQeAoKVT/10oqgrMEl8EkAvaW5tA2MbaTcSoBzuZG2L0A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>82</s> 76 bytes

```python
i=input()
for x in"aeiouAEIOU":i=i.replace(x,x+"f"+x).replace(x*2,x)
print i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9M2M6@gtERDkystv0ihQiEzTykxNTO/1NHV0z9UyQoorVeUWpCTmJyqUaFToa2UpqRdoYkQ0jLSqdDkKijKzCtRyPz/X8k5Pz9HIT0xN1UJAA)

Actually shorter to use 2 replaces rather than the split and join that was there previously.

If we are required to have "Abc" output "Afabc" instead of "AfAbc" then that costs another 8 bytes...

```python
i=input()
for x in"aeiouAEIOU":i=i.replace(x,x+"f"+x.lower()).replace(x*2,x)
print i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9M2M6@gtERDkystv0ihQiEzTykxNTO/1NHV0z9UyQoorVeUWpCTmJyqUaFToa2UpqRdoZeTX55apKGpiZDSMtKp0OQqKMrMK1HI/P9fyTEpWQkA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 102 bytes

### 102 bytes

```cs
s=>string.Concat(s.Select((c,i)=>c+("aeiouAEIOU".Contains(c)?"f"+(++i<s.Length&&s[i]==c?"":c+""):"")))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDBSgMxFEX3@YqQRUmYOh/QaVqkqAgVhSIuxEV4JtPQNMF5GUFKv31803agiO0iJPdyct9NAG8gNbZr0cear34w223FzlW5SCFYyD5FLB9stI2HP8TSx6@KQTCI/GXHMJvsgd@3EaaYGwLH/LjPuNO8Qz07SoqOYLLEcmX7EVLC2Cs9g0IKY31qb@8en19Fj2XjI0pQc@FEIYvCT7Fc2ljn9WiE7/5Da5gLMYFCCDWhpVRXsaHJd/Kf/IkSpGI7RmmYgi3fGp8tVbfSSbFOLVqhuNaczi61jrQjp/qfD2Yz4ME4EldYatGcWDq6XlwgN/QpJ3Lj3UFcyrSmgfWQStP73N64wC9SCrw226H0gt7oDpYj80r5s4uE7Nm@@wU)

Linq version, looking for improvement :)

### 132 bytes

```cs
s=>{var r="";int l=s.Length,i=0;for(;i<l;){var c=s[i];r+=c+("aeiouAEIOU".Contains(s[i++])?"f"+(i<l&&s[i]==c?"":c+""):"");}return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBBSwMxEIXv@RVDDmWXrYvnpmmRoiJUFEQ8SA8hJu3QNMEkW5Cyv32drV0QsT2EzBu@eXkTna50iKZrEvo1vHylbHaC/Vb1IjhndMbgU31vvImo/xBL9J@CaadSgucDS1ll1HDXeD1NORI4hp97BlZCBwBJzg57FSFKzgX6DE6memn8Om/GKK@FDbEQOHWiPGJapndciVhJXRVcGQzNze3D0yuncD4r9KkgoKpW5ZxbXhU0ORr1I1LqOecTXXFeTuiINprcRA9RtJ1gQ9R9wA94JJ@iZAdGnik4U79FzIZ2M4Ut@CY0yfASpASqbWgsaUsd8T/v1HbAnbIkLrCUIp5YKm0vzpBb@sQTuUV7FOc8jYp6M7jS671v3zjDL0JwsFa7IfSCdrTHlqXmhfC/BglpWdt9Aw)

flat C# solution, looking for improvement :)

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 218 bytes

Pretty blunt:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"a","afa"),"e","efe"),"i","ifi"),"o","ofo"),"u","ufu"),"aa","a"),"ee","e"),"ii","i"),"oo","o"),"uu","u")
```

Substitutes `a`, `e`, `i`, `o` & `u` with `*f*`.  Followed by removing all duplicate vowels in turn.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 40 characters

```
perl -pe 's/([aeiou])\1?/$1."f\L$1"x length$&/egi'
```

I've waited a long time to make use of perl's `\L` regex feature. A long time.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 118 bytes

```c
f(char*s){char*u="aeiou",v[4]={0};for(;*v=v[2]=*s++;)printf("%s%s%s"+!strchr(u,*v|=(*v>64)*32)*4,v+2,"f",*s-*v?v:"");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BbsMgEETv/gpKVQnWpGocK4cQ3EM@w/IBEWMjJSaCeC@uv53inKI9zNOMZsfsBmPSp5vMbb725ByfV@e/x6Z4t4Kbhuwly8yoA0S@vHRWVPfOz1RgW3dq@Vml9YFJQIVt1SmIZSn5I7efltGvuB0tP/I/MwY2C8A/xQCbY83hUHGoBZaVoJYKiDvAXzxRyuWacp/ctZvYBjoMRmzzBCAzcrIUhDjLtqDZc/IibPcdl8Wa0sX7Gxn0vf8H)

Comment: [104 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY3LDoIwFET3fEWtMWkv@AAfCxFd@BmERVMoNoHWULwxQb69git3kzOZOXJdS@mX2sjmVVbk4vpS283jGvyjTpt6Yl4x@RAdOD4o2zFteoL5ociG3ZgCZpgnRQYuDFP@nBa9YnTl1MrRcKFNWb0ZFZW2LxoBfjLA7ekI@4TDPsIwicCtAW94ppSno5@vW6HNzyG6WkazmABMGTkZAkK0YnNxjTn5JczjgqfB6P3d2obUoq2@ "C (gcc) – Try It Online")